# mat-grid-list not appearing correctly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use angular material in my project.

I have the following

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
        <mat-grid-tile class="item-file-grid" *ngFor="let ind of [1,2,3,4]"></mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

in my module I have the following import

```
  imports: [
    CommonComponentModule,
    SharedModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
```

But the result is not working, I have no error, but the module is not doing a grid like in the demo. https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview

I have the following, even tho my container is way bigger, looks like a simple div

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you import MatGridListModule in your angular module?

```
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
```

Comment: oh, I am an idiot, I just see in the doc that there is the import to do in overview... I thought matmodule did everything